# NVIDIA driver not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

Under Ubuntu 18.04, I tried installing the Nvidia recommended driver with

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-418
```

I rebooted, and when I try to run `nvidia-settings` to check if everything is good I get

```
$ nvidia-settings
ERROR: Unable to find display on any available system


(nvidia-settings:24546): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:26:26.552: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 17:26:26.554: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 17:26:26.554: PRIME: is it supported? yes
```

I also tried with the previous versions (415, 410, 390) and I have the same problem.

Here is my setting:

```
~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208GLM [Quadro K610M] (rev a1)
```

Anyone has a clue of what is going on ?

Thank you !

EDIT: here is the output of the commands:

```
~$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode
```

```
~$ ls /sys/firmware/efi/
config_table  fw_platform_size  runtime      systab
efivars       fw_vendor         runtime-map  vars
```

```
~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: GK208GLM [Quadro K610M]
       fabriquant: NVIDIA Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       ressources: irq:37 mémoire:cd000000-cdffffff mémoire:50000000-5fffffff mémoire:60000000-61ffffff portE/S:5000(taille=128) mémoire:ce000000-ce07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       ressources: irq:36 mémoire:ce400000-ce7fffff mémoire:a0000000-afffffff portE/S:6000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

```
~$ dkms status
nvidia, 418.56, 4.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
~$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm            798720  0
nvidia_drm             45056  2
nvidia_modeset       1085440  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              17600512  47 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 nvidia_drm,i915
ipmi_msghandler        53248  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
drm                   401408  29 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
```

EDIT:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
```

```
$ env | grep -i wayland
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu-wayland
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu-wayland:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu-wayland
GDMSESSION=ubuntu-wayland
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu-wayland:/etc/xdg
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add hardware (exact Nvidia chipset) info. You may not be using the correct driver version.

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `mokutil --sb-state` 2. `ls /sys/firmware/efi/` 3. `sudo lshw -c video`  4. `dkms status` and 5. `lsmod | grep nvidia`

Comment: @Radu Dragomir, is your display server **wayland** by any chance? Issue  commands: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and `env | grep -i wayland` and make sure that `wayland` is not displayed. Please report.

Comment: Yes it is wayland ! I added the command output to the post.

Comment: Please perform the following changes in the GDM3 custom configuration file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.  If there is a line `#WaylandEnable=false`, then remove the comments. By uncommenting the above line your system will use the Xorg display manager instead of Wayland next time it boots. **Reboot the system**. Please issue command `nvidia-settings` and see the result. Also check that you can access Nvidia graphics.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion ! However I just tried this, and the screen froze when rebooting (nothing happened), so I had to go to recovery mode and enable Wayland again. I guess this is an issue with Xorg ?

Comment: When you make a GUI login (desktop), you will see a `gear` icon. If you click the icon, there will be options popped out: `"Ubuntu"` and `"Ubuntu on Wayland"`. Do you see them? If so, why don't you select ubuntu and login? Type `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and if the output is `x11` you are through. Or else make a re-attempt to remove comment `#WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and then issue  command: `sudo systemctl restart gdm`. This will take you to `login` screen. If screen flickers then **reboot system**. Issue command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and check for `x11`.

Comment: I tried this, and Ubuntu with the X11 display server does not boot (the screen freezes right after login), so I switched back to Wayland. X11 does not seem to work, I tried to reinstall it but I get the same problem.

Comment: If `gdm3` has problems, then choose `lightdm` as a workaround. Open up a terminal and issue command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. There will be a window popped up. Use Up/Dn arrows and place cursor on `lightdm`. Hit `spacebar` to select it. Then hit `tab` to move to 'ok' and finally type `return`. Now issue one more command: `sudo service lightdm restart` and you will find that X restarts to work. Issue command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and check for `x11`.

Comment: It worked now, thank you so much ! I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` and started by switching to `Ubuntu` instead of `Ubuntu on Wayland`, now my nvidia driver is working.

Comment: I am glad that your problem was solved! Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Marmayogi, my issue was that I was running the Wayland display server.

I had to reconfigure the Xorg display server with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`, rebooted and switched to it. Now the NVIDIA driver 418 works correctly.