# Nvidia drivers not working on Ubuntu 21.04, kernel 5.13, ASUS ROG Zephyrus G15(2021)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

the output for `nvidia-settings` is:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:3137): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 22:32:23.574: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 22:32:23.578: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 22:32:23.578: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I checked another answer and found out that my display server was **wayland** and followed the instructions to set it to xorg and rebooted but still got the same output for `nvidia-settings`

Also the output for `sudo prime-select nvidia` is:

```
Error: no integrated GPU detected.
```

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133321/nvidia-driver-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04) was the answer that I followed. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Last I tested, the Nvidia driver didn't work properly with Linux 5.13, you may be better off with a `5.12.x` version.  Also, since you're on a G15, I highly recommend installing https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/asusctl